# Dosbox:Increase no of buffers

Tags: windows, dosbox

I am trying to use DOSBox to run a 16-bit DOS program in 64-bit Windows. It requires a buffer value of 99 in order to run.  DOSBox's initially sets the buffer to 50.  How can I change this setting to 99?  I have searched everywhere but all the information I find says to recompile DOSBox but I am unable to find what to do after that. I have the open source files of dosbox but cant find buffer parameter and its value.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a new text file in the root of your **mounted C-drive** and name it as CONFIG.SYS

```
BUFFERS=99
```

Comment: Means the c drive i mount should have a config.sys file having buffers value?

Comment: Dosbox doesnt use config.sys as far i have researched.

Comment: Though [DOSBox Wiki](http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/AUTOEXEC) mentions it replaces most of what config.sys they don't actually say it isn't used.  Did you try a config.sys file with the defined line?

Comment: @Varun  Yes, the C drive within DOSBox should have a config.sys.    You should try it anyway.